# Load dynamic images on Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angularjs and I need to display an image when a thumbnail is clicked.
I wanted to display its Preview picture. It will be fetched on my database.

My Database table on mysql goes something like this:

Materials:{
[name:'material1',
thumbnail:'thumbnail1', 
preview:'preview1'],

[name:'material2',
thumbnail:'thumbnail2', 
preview:'preview2']
}

I'm also using Laravel as my backend framework. The list of materials are now Displaying but when I clicked on the thumbnail the preview image didn't appear. Is there any way i can fix this?

```js
var imageCtrl = function($scope, $http) {

  $scope.materials = [];
  $scope.init = function(){
    $http.get('api/materials').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config){
      $scope.materials = data;
    });
  }

  $scope.loadimage = function() {
    $scope.image.path = $scope.materials.preview;
  }
};

app.controller('imageCtrl', imageCtrl);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="imageCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='material in materials'>
      <div>@{{material.name}}</div>
      <a href=""><img ng-src="@{{material.thumbnail}}" alt="" ng-click="loadimage()></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <img ng-src="@{{image.path}}" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: you should pass current 'material' to loadImage & then initialize material.preview  to image.path

Comment: how could i pass the material to loadimage?

Answer (score 0):

On your html page, pass current material object to loadImage function.

`<div ng-controller="imageCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='material in materials'>
      <div>{{material.name}}</div>
      <img ng-src="{{material.thumbnail}}" ng-click="loadimage(material)>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <img ng-src="{{image.path}}" alt="">
</div>`

and then from inside controller, update image object.

```
 $scope.loadimage = function(material) {
   $scope.image.path = $scope.material.preview;
 }
```